# How do I use a Unix script to select a Verilog test file?

Tags: scripting, verilog

I have to do the verification of DPRAM.

Each test case is written in different file named test1.v,test2.v etc.

I want to write a script(unix) such that when I type run test1.v then only that test case will run.

Note :- test1.v contents only task which includes read assert,write assert etc.

The test bench is a separate file which includes clock and component instantiation.

when run test1.v is done then it should link the test1.v task to the testbench and then output is obtained.

I have done the coding in verilog

How to do this?

Comment: Use `ifdef in the Verilog and control it through an environment variable in your shell script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as far as I can make out, your different tests, or 'testcases' are in files named `test<n>.v`. And I'll assume that each of these testcases has a task that has the same name in all files, say `run_testcase`. This means that your testbench (`testbench.v`, say) must look something like:

```
module testbench();   
   ...
   `include "test.v" // <- problem is this line
   ...
   initial begin 
     // Some setup
     run_testcase();
     //
     $finish;
  end
endmodule
```

So your problem is the `include` line - a different file needs to be included depending on the testcase. I can think of two ways of solving this first one is as **toolic** suggested - using a symbolic link to 'rename' the testcase file. So an example wrapper script (`run_sim1`) to launch your sim might look a bit like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
testcase=$1
ln -sf ${testcase} test.v
my_simulator testbench.v
```

Another way is to use a macro, and define this in the wrapper script for your simulation. Your testbench would be modified to look like:

```
   ...
   `include `TESTCASE
   ...
```

And the wrapper script (`run_sim2`):

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
testcase=$1
my_simulator testbench.v +define+TESTCASE=\"${testcase}\"
```

The quotes are important here, as the verilog `include` directive expects them. Unfortunately, we can't leave the quotes in the testbench because it will then look like a string to verilog, and the `TESTCASE` macro won't be expanded.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to have the testbench file include a test file with a generic name:

```
`include "test.v"
```

Then, have your script create a symbolic link to the test you want to run.  For example, in a shell script or Makefile, to run `test1.v`:

```
ln -sf test1.v test.v
run_sim
```

To run `test2.v`, your script would substitute test2 for test1, etc.